# NativeAudio not working on ionic 2 rc0 and rc1

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic2

I'm in the middle of creating a Sound provider for button taps and background game music. In My Sound provider called sound.ts I'm using the [*NativeAudio*](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/nativeaudio/) plugin and have defined a function for preloading my sound data. But when I'm building my app with

> ionic run android -c

I get the following Error message:

> ngc: Error:
>   Property 'preloadSimple' does not exist on type 'NativeAudio'.

**sound.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeAudio } from 'ionic-native';
...
@Injectable()
export class Sound {

  constructor(
    public nativeAudio : NativeAudio
  ){}

  loadSounds(){
    return this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('buttonTick', 'assets/sounds/button-tick.wav')
      .then(()=>{
        return Promise.resolve("loaded sounds successfully");
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
...
```

In my app.component.ts I'm firing the loadSounds() method of my Sound provider

**app.component.ts**

```
import ... //  Config/Sound/...
...

  constructor(
    public platform : Platform,
    public config   : Config,
    public sound    : Sound
  ){

    platform.ready().then(() => {

      // loading config & sounds
      config.loadDefault()
        .then(msg => {
          console.log(msg);
          return sound.loadSounds(); <----------(HERE)
        })
        .then(msg => {
          console.log(msg);
        })
        .catch(err => {
...
```

My app.module.ts injects the *NativeAudio* provider and my custom Sound provider. 
So I come to question if there is something wrong with the plugin for rc0 or if I miss something ?

Do I have to declare NativeAudio somehow, and how do I declare a plugin in my povider .ts file ? because I guess this is a typescript error ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, the reason the error came where because of using NativeAudio (from ionic/native) like a non native module.

```
  constructor(
    public nativeAudio : NativeAudio <---- HAD TO DELETE THIS
  ){}
```

and afterwards I shouldnt use "this" in front of NativeAudio